# Simple CreateProcess() Explanation

Tags: c++, windows

How do you use CreateProcess() to launch a program? I think a good example would be a commented piece of code like so.

```
int function() {
  dox(int a, char b); //This does this and you should use it for this
  doz(bool c); //You should use this for this
  if (thisstatus == thatthing) {  //The variable thisthing should contain that
     doy(variable); //This does this and this
  }
```

Comment: I don't get what your pseudo-code example should have to do with `CreateProcess()`? Also what in particular you don't understand from the MSDN pages?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The example has nothing to do with `CreateProcess`, he basically wants a code example of how to use `CreateProcess` with explanation about what every line of code does.

Comment: The code example is a template of one possible way to format the code in a way I understand

Comment: @Borgleader I see. But I don't see how this improves this question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It doesn't, I'm just explaining what he wants. (I voted to close his original question)

Comment: The MSDN documentation links to this example which seems pretty straight forwards for a basic use case to me. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't have a clue what is happening in that example or how on earth I am supposed to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looking at the [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx) sample from MSDN

```
// Start the child process. 
if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    argv[1],        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
) 
{
    printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}
```

I think it's documented well enough in comments for the examples context.

You may want to elaborate in your question which of the comments there aren't understandable for you, such I could try to explain more (but in general they are explained with the sample IMHO).

Comment: I don't get how I am supposed to use this eg. Where do I put the program's .exe

Comment: @BC5 As the comments tell, this sample uses a full command line, and the programs .exe is the 1st parameter: `"myexe.exe param1 param2"` of a string containing that command line.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks, It seems it was all there, I just didn't know the terminology, Thanks